# Select extent on canvas - QGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, extents

I'm designing a QGIS plugin where I'd like to offer the user the functionality to select the extent of a bounding box from the canvas like in some tools like `Create grid`.

[image]
I've explored QT Designer but there is no widget with this functionality.

I have also explored the tool code of tools that offer this functionality but found nothing.

Finally, I didn't find any documentation about this feature. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is a Qt contextual menu on a QPushButton `...` with an action that retrieves the `QgsMapCanvas.extent()` ([pyQGIS API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapCanvas.html?highlight=qgsmapcanvas#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.extent)).

Comment: You could check how it is used from the [ExtentSelectionPanel.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/8a3c7b14c367771d096b4a6d006aa3c4b1017dd5/python/plugins/processing/gui/ExtentSelectionPanel.py#L129) file.

Comment: I was looking for a similar script! I'll explore it on Monday, along with the API documentation. I'll get back to you, have a good weekend!

Comment: I solved my problem ! Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @VincentBré If you have solved your question, it would still be helpful to post the answer for others who end up here

Answer (score 3):

**You mean select a region on the map, on the Canvas map? And that the selected region is shown on the map by clicking and dragging the cursor? From a dialog box or button? And capture the coordinates of the region for a process?**

In that case, you must create a custom map tool that interacts with the mapCanvas. That is, write a class that extends QgsMapTool or QgsMapToolEmitPoint.

In the cookbook they explain in detail how to do it, here https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#id4
Go to the item *Writing Custom Map Tools*

The map tools require the mapCanvas on which they will act. Inside the class you must rewrite the different events, for example

> def canvasPressEvent(self, event):

The event gives you the coordinates where you clicked `event.pos().x()` in screen coordinates, but you can convert them to map coordinates if you previously, in the init, create a `QgsCoordinateTransform`, for example with:

> self.transform = self.can.getCoordinateTransform()

Concerning the trace of the rectangle drawn by the user, you use a `QgsRubberBand` that requires the mapCanvas and the geometry it will represent.

To activate the tool after clicking a button, simply create an instance of your tool (QgsMapTool), `tool=youTool(canvas)` and then activate it by assigning it to the canvas with `iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(youTool)`.

There are several things to consider but this will guide you if you are going to create your own mapTool for what you want.

Comment: I have already solved my problem. Thanks for your answer and your explanations.